# is Bluetooth SIG registration required?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I'm using a Bluetooth module that is certified and meets all needed regulatory requirements. I tested my end product for all the EMC requirements. I do not care about using the Bluetooth Logo. can I sell my product without registering it with the Bluetooth SIG.?
Can I just claim in my documentation that the product is "designed for BLE compatibility"?

Please note this question is purely about Bluetooth SIG requirements and not about regulatory compliance.

Answer (score 2):

After registering and qualifying our first-gen BLE product, we displayed our second-gen product on our website. Within a year, we received an enforcement letter from Bluetooth SIG, requesting completion of qualification for the second-gen product. We have submitted a correction plan, but we are considering removing the Bluetooth brand from our product description. Not sure if it's worth the $2.5k.

Answer (score 1):

As described on Bluetooth SIG

> To brand (or re-brand) and sell a Bluetooth® product, your company must join the Bluetooth Special Interest Group (SIG) and complete the Qualification process
>
> ALL Bluetooth® Products Must Be Qualified
>
> Product qualifications cannot be inherited from your supplier. You must complete the qualification of your product for yourself.
>
> You can only qualify your products under your member company's account and only by completing the Bluetooth Qualification Process.
>
> It may be possible to complete product qualification by adding the product as a new model to one of your existing qualifications. Or you may need to create a new qualification which may require testing to be completed. The Bluetooth Qualification tool, Launch Studio, can guide you through the appropriate path.

https://support.bluetooth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049018272-Do-I-Need-to-Qualify-

Also here is good description: https://cetecomadvanced.com/en/certification/bluetooth-sig-certification/

Comment: Hi mike,
I do understand what the Bluetooth is requiring.
1) I don't see the legal justification. if I do not use the logo or the Bluetooth name anywhere in the product or the documentation. I checked the terms and conditions for the BLE module and for the BLE stack we are using. We do meet both of them without registering with SIG as there is no mention about the registration.
2) I do not see the logical justification to have to register with the SIG group. They don’t actually test my product for compatibility. They just list it. Thanks
Joe

Comment: I did not check there rules for a long time actually but when I registered on SIG a long time ago there was only one requirement for legal use "Bluetooth" word for software products is just to be registered with SIG. Nothing more. However, for hardware products you have to pass their certification. Without that you can not use "Bluetooth" (it is registered TM) in your product naming anyhow.

Comment: Mike. from a legal point of view, I am not using the Bluetooth trademark or Logo, So I can't see why I can't I sell my product without registering it? And from an ethical point of view, we are buying a module and a stack that already paid their dues to the SIG.

Comment: In such case I think it should be OK to forget about SIG and simple sell your product without any problems.